# Natbib+style alpha: getting all authors' initials

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle

I am using natbib with the style *alpha*:

```
\usepackage[numbers,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

However, what this produces, for papers with more than three authors, is a citation key of the form `[ABC⁺00]` instead of, say, `[ABCDEF00]`.

Is there a package option I can use to obtain the latter behaviour?

Comment: I'm not aware of such an option for the combination of the `alpha` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package. Maybe there's a way forward with `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `natbib` option to do this. You can only influence the alphabetic label produced by `alpha` if you modify (a copy of) `alpha.bst` directly.

(Note that `alpha` isn't even a `natbib` style and that `natbib` supports mainly numeric and author-year citations, but not alphabetic styles. It probably works well enough if you don't try to use `\citet` or `\citeauthor` and friends, but I thought I should mention this.)

1. Locate `alpha.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich alpha.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/alpha.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `alpha-all.bst`, say (the license of the file only allows distribution of modified copies if they bear a different name)
4. Find `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}` (ll. 934-973) and replace the complete function definition with

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
   { 's :=
     s num.names$ 'numnames :=
     numnames #1 >
       { numnames 'namesleft :=
         #1 'nameptr :=
         ""
           { namesleft #0 > }
           { nameptr numnames =
               { s nameptr "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                   { "{\etalchar{+}}" *
                     #1 'et.al.char.used :=
                   }
                   { s nameptr "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$ * }
                 if$
               }
               { s nameptr "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$ * }
             if$
             nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
             namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
           }
         while$
       }
       { s #1 "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$
         duplicate$ text.length$ #2 <
           { pop$ s #1 "{ll}" format.name$ #3 text.prefix$ }
           'skip$
         if$
       }
     if$
   }
   ```
5. Add a comment with your name, the current date and a short description of the changes to the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{alpha-all}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` in your document.

As alternative for steps 1 to 5 you can obtain the patched version of the file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/372397ed6d91f516ba71eec0097a376a

The diff between `alpha.bst` and the new `alpha-all.bst` should look roughly like this

```diff
--- alpha.bst   2010-12-09 04:18:56.000000000 +0100
+++ alpha-all.bst   2021-02-16 17:49:17.801451700 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,14 @@
+%%%%% alpha-all.bst
+%%%%%
+%%%%% for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583586/35864
+%%%%%
+%%%%% 2021-02-16 MW
+%%%%%
+%%%%% modification of alpha.bst
+%%%%% that displays all author letters in the alphabetic label
+%%%%% and does not truncate the list with \etalchar{+}
+%%%%% the only change is a slight simplification of format.lab.names
+%%%%%
 % BibTeX standard bibliography style `alpha'
    % Version 0.99b (8-Dec-10 release) for BibTeX versions 0.99a or later.
    % Copyright (C) 1984, 1985, 1988, 2010 Howard Trickey and Oren Patashnik.
@@ -935,10 +946,7 @@
 { 's :=
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames #1 >
-    { numnames #4 >
-        { #3 'namesleft := }
-        { numnames 'namesleft := }
-      if$
+    { numnames 'namesleft :=
       #1 'nameptr :=
       ""
         { namesleft #0 > }
@@ -956,12 +964,6 @@
           namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
         }
       while$
-      numnames #4 >
-        { "{\etalchar{+}}" *
-          #1 'et.al.char.used :=
-        }
-        'skip$
-      if$
     }
     { s #1 "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$
       duplicate$ text.length$ #2 <
```

Now

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[numbers,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Annie Hacker and Humphrey Appleby and Bernard Woolley and James Hacker},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \citep{elk}

\bibliographystyle{alpha-all}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: Lorem (EHAWH72)]

---

Here's how you would do the same thing with `biblatex`, which does have an option for this (`maxalphanames`).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, maxbibnames=999, maxalphanames=999]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Annie Hacker and Humphrey Appleby and Bernard Woolley and James Hacker},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [EHAWH72]]

Comment: Thank you! Welll... Biblatex it is, I guess.